# Sanitizing the key in an array

Tags: php, security, sanitization

Say I have an array of key-value pairs with non-numerical keys. If I am going to be using those keys as values in an SQL INSERT statement, is it important to sanitize them as well?

Something like:

```
$food = array('fruit'=>'apple', 'veggie'=>'tomato', 'bread'=>'wheat');
foreach($food as $foodType => $nameOfFood)
{
    $nameOfFood = stripslashes($nameOfFood);
    $foodType = stripslashes($foodType); //Is this necessary?
    $query = "INSERT INTO Foods(FoodType, NameOfFood) VALUES ($foodType, $nameOfFood)";
    // Execute query
}
```

If the `$food` array was populated through a POST statement, would sanitizing the keys be a concern?

Comment: If the keys are user generated, they yes. The basic rule is ***Never*** *trust user input*.

Comment: if it's user input, yes; sanitize. Btw, that looks like pseudo code here. Those values are strings and require them to be quoted.

Comment: Yes and no. If you set it, then you don't need to input. But you also need to think of script injection. I'd suggest using PDO or mysqli, with binding so that you don't have the worry about doing it yourself.

Comment: `stripslashes()` doesn't safeguard against an SQL injection, a prepared statement does.